# R: reshape a dataframe by creating columns for a specific element (control treatment)

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider a data frame showing results for the control and two experimental treatments for males and females together with the sizes for each treatment:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- data_frame( treatment = c('ctrl','low','high','ctrl','low','high'), 
                gender = c('male','male','male','female','female','female'),
                size = c(10,20,30,10,20,30),
                result = c(0.11, 0.32, 0.25, 0.15, 0.38, 0.55) )

treatment  gender   size results
 ctrl       male     10    0.11
 low        male     20    0.32
 high       male     30    0.25
 ctrl       female   10    0.15
 low        female   20    0.35
 high       female   30    0.55
```

To compare the control with experimental treatments side by side, I'd like to reshape the dataframe as follows:

```
treatment gender   ctrl_size    size   ctrl_result  result
   low     female        10      20        0.15      0.38
  high     female        10      30        0.15      0.55
   low     male          10      20        0.11      0.32
  high     male          10      30        0.11      0.25
```

My attempt below works but seems cumbersome to me as it creates auxiliary data frames before merging them into the final one:

```
mydf_result <- mydf %>%
  select(-size) %>% 
  spread(treatment, result) %>%
  gather(treatment, result, c(low, high) ) %>% 
  rename(ctrl_result = ctrl)

mydf_size <- mydf %>%
  select(-result) %>%  
  spread(treatment, size) %>% 
  gather(treatment, size, c(low, high))  %>% 
  rename(ctrl_size = ctrl)

mydf_final <- 
  full_join(mydf_result, mydf_size, by = c('treatment', 'gender')) %>% 
  select(treatment, gender, ctrl_size, size, ctrl_result, result) %>%
  arrange(gender)

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  treatment gender ctrl_size  size ctrl_result result
      <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1       low female        10    20        0.15   0.38
2      high female        10    30        0.15   0.55
3       low   male        10    20        0.11   0.32
4      high   male        10    30        0.11   0.25
```

Can the above be achieved within one pipeline?

Comment: Don't we need to know which observations in `mydf` are from the same individual to be able to do this?

Comment: Thank you, @Joe. I see  a column for 'treatment' missing and will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure the desired result is the tidiest arrangement, you can rearrange like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% gather(var, val, size, result) %>%    # gather all numbers into one column
    spread(treatment, val) %>%    # spread treatment so ctrl can be separated
    gather(treatment, ttmt, high, low) %>%    # regather high and low separately
    gather(ct_tm, val, ctrl, ttmt) %>%    # regather numbers, now with ctrl/ttmt separated
    unite(var, ct_tm, var) %>%    # join column labels
    spread(var, val)    # spread to wide

## # A tibble: 4 × 6
##   gender treatment ctrl_result ctrl_size ttmt_result ttmt_size
## *  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 female      high        0.15        10        0.55        30
## 2 female       low        0.15        10        0.38        20
## 3   male      high        0.11        10        0.25        30
## 4   male       low        0.11        10        0.32        20
```

Comment: that's elegant and short. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(mydf)[treatment!="ctrl"][mydf[treatment=="ctrl"],
  on = "gender"], c("i.size", "i.result"), c("ctrl_size", "ctrl_result"))[,
                  i.treatment := NULL][]
#    treatment gender size result ctrl_size ctrl_result
#1:       low   male   20   0.32        10        0.11
#2:      high   male   30   0.25        10        0.11
#3:       low female   20   0.38        10        0.15
#4:      high female   30   0.55        10        0.15
```